# How to connect to postgreSQL from others machine in local network with scalalikejdbc

Tags: postgresql, scala

I just began to learn about scala and want to find a way to connect to PostgreSQL with scalalikejdbc. I set up PostgreSQL on machine1 and want to connect to one from machine2.
This is my PostgreSQL configurations:

- postgresql.conf

```html
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
```

- pg_hba.conf

```html
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
host    all             postgres        192.168.1.1/24         md5
```

- This is my piece of code to connect to PostgreSQL that written by scala

```html
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    val jdbcUser = "postgres"
    val jdbcPassword = "******"
    val jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.50.1:5432/jdbc"

    Class.forName(jdbcDriver)
    ConnectionPool.singleton(jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPassword)
    val data = DB.readOnly { implicit session =>
      sql"""SELECT * FROM Users""".
        map { resultSet =>
          resultSet.int(1) -> resultSet.int(2)
        }
        .list.apply().toMap
    }
```

I get an error that "Connection to 192.168.50.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."
Anyone can explain to me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to substitute 192.168.50.1/24 instead of 192.168.1.1/24 in your pg_hba.conf. And then restart your postgres service in your remote server.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the config?

Comment: Yes I restarted the server, but still not to connect.